# send value from client side to server side using C# in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a website content management using asp.net and C# and bootstrap. I already done this using asp.net and C# and a server control like gridview but I want create this version one like as wordpress CMS.
I will describe my project to clear my purpose.
First I fill a `DataTable` from database. This `Datatable` has `messageId int`, `Subject varchar`, `name varchar`, `email varchar`, `message text`, `isRead bit`, and so on columns.isRead column is bit type for specifies that the message is read or not.
I Fill my DataTable using below Method:

> `DataTable dt = cls.Fill_In_DataTable("MessageFetchMessage");`

Then I generate html text using another method dynamically: on Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   messeges = cls.fetchMessages();
}
```

messege the string variable, will append generated html code to aspx page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Last messages From users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="list-group">
                <%=messeges %>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right">
                <a href="#">View All messages <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the message content has these text from `fetchMessages()`method:

```
public string fetchMessages()
{
    string post = ""; string readed = "";
    DataTable dt = cls.Fill_In_DataTable("MessageFetchMessage");
    if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dtTemp = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["messageDate"].ToString());

            if (dt.Rows[i]["isRead"].ToString() == "True")
                readed = "MessageReaded"; 
            else
                readed = "MessageNew";
            post += "<div class='modal fade' id='myModal" + dt.Rows[i]["messageId"].ToString() + "' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>"
                + "<div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>"
                + "<div class='modal-content'>"
                + "<div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'><span style='font-weight:bold'>Subject</span> : " + dt.Rows[i]["subject"].ToString() + "</h4></div>"
                + "<div class='modal-header'><p><span style='font-weight:bold'>Date</span> : " + dtTemp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "</p>"
                + "<p><span style='font-weight:bold'>Time</span> : " + dt.Rows[i]["messageTime"].ToString() + "</p>"
                + "<p><span style='font-weight:bold'>Email</span> : " + dt.Rows[i]["email"].ToString() + "</p></div>"
                + "<div class='modal-body'>" + dt.Rows[i]["message"].ToString() + "</div>"
                + "<div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button><input type='submit' ID='btn" + dt.Rows[i]["messageId"].ToString() + "'  class='btn btn-danger' onserverclick='btn_Click' value='Delete message' /></div>"    
                + "</div></div></div>";
            string narrow = Special.TimeToNarrow(dt.Rows[i]["messageDate"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["messageTime"].ToString());
            post += "<a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal" + dt.Rows[i]["messageId"].ToString() + "' href='#' class='list-group-item " + readed + "'><span class='badge'>" + narrow + "</span><i class='fa fa-fw fa-comment'></i> <span>"
                 + dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString() + "</span> : <span>" + dt.Rows[i]["subject"].ToString() + "</span></a>";
        }
    }

    return post;
}
```

finally I add server code behind for btn_Click Event:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = (sender as Control).ClientID;
    //Then give Id to database class for CRUD Intractions
}
```

but btn_Click never called from client side. I search for similar question within 2 days and didn't get answer. please help me :)

Here I will put my Website screen Shots:

[image]
Then after click on one of the rows a pop up window will show using modal bootstrap:
[image]

Comment: You require a WebMethod. Do you know how to use those?

Comment: no I'm not :( sorry could you please explain me more?

Comment: Ya no worries, I will post an answer.

Comment: Well, I should ask you bit more about what you are trying to do. Do you have to generate the HTML and the Bootstrap modal on the server side?

Comment: yes I did and I want get message Id from delete modal button

Comment: Is the Client ID empty upon click event?

Comment: the problem is btn_Click won't call because I can't add runat='server' to generated html code :(

Comment: there aren't any error just won't call , I already trace the btn_Click event but nothing happend after I click on delete modal button

Comment: I would recommend rearranging your code a bit. How about, adding your modal to the mark up along with the button. Then you can use runat=server and get your data based on the click event or an AJAX call to a web method. The content in the modal and everything else can be generated server side, still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101748/discussion-between-blue-moon-and-snowyetis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Modal, button and any other mark up you have to the ASPX page (mark up). Then you can get your ID on click event. The dynamic generation of your code is not registering the controls with the server side in Webforms.

Once you have captured your Message ID, you can place it in ViewState, Session or a hidden field on the UI. That way you can have the ID to use whenever you need it.

Comment: thanks a lot 'snowYetis' you very well helped me here and with chat

Comment: @BlueMoon anytime, glad I could help.